# How do I check the maximum output refresh rate (hz) for my MacBookPro？

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Is there any place I can get what is the maximum output fresh rate (in Hz) of my MacBook Pro?

I am considering buying a new monitor for my mbp. But I don't know how to check the maximum refresh rate.

I am using `MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)` with `11.4 (20F71) Big Sur`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try reading [MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP776?locale=en_US). The answer would appear to be 60 Hz.